# Add network account to local group with Puppet?

Tags: macos, osx-server, puppet

On a client Mac joined to an OS X Server Open Directory, is it possible to use Puppet to add a directory account to a local group on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppet does not integrate with LDAP / AD / Open Directory, so the user that you will be adding will only be a local account.

Run the following on a different user that was made with Open Directory

```
puppet resource user foo
```

(Here is the output from my mac tied to Active Directory, yours should look similar)

```
puppet resource user foo
user { 'foo':
  ensure   => 'present',
  comment  => 'Foo Bar',
  gid      => '72910xxxx',
  groups   => ['_appserveradm', '_appserverusr', '_lpadmin', 'admin', 'com.apple.access_ssh-disabled', 'com.apple.sharepoint.group.2'],
  home     => '/Users/foo',
  password => '*',
  shell    => '/bin/bash',
  uid      => '104763xxxx',
}
```